# Azure storage sync unable to create cloud endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files, azure-file-share

In azure storage sync while trying to create a cloud endpoint I am getting the below error message to enter image description here

[image]

I am getting the following error -

Cloud endpoint creation failed.

Code: Authorization failed.
Details: The client xxxxxx with object ID xxxxxxxxx doesn't have authorization to perform action xxxxxxxxx

Please help me out for the above mentioned problem statement which also contains the error message.

Comment: The Error message represents your account doesn't have write permission on defined scope.so you need to add required permissions. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-assign-permissions?tabs=azure-portal it may helps.

Comment: you can check this by Enable AD ownership to azure file share. Set share-level-permissions to “Enable permissions for all authenticated users and users. If possible, try to modify your question by modifying error image into text format, then only community members can provide complete solution.

Comment: @vijaya - As requested, I have edited the error message in the text format. Please verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error message represents y**our account doesn't have role assignment permissions and write permission on defined scope. so, you need to add required permissions**.
After reproducing from my end getting the same error and below are the steps followed.

- Created Storage account.
  [image]
- Then Create File share in Storage account.
  [image]
- Then Create file sync by taking previously created storage a/c and file share name as shown below.
  [image]
  Getting the same error as to create cloud end what it needs required permissions.
  [image]

For above error, you need to

Step1: Enable AD ownership to azure file share.

Step2:Set share-level-permissions to “Enable permissions for all authenticated users and users”

Then save.
[image]

Then only cloud end will create.

If you are unable to add required permissions as mentioned above, I am suggesting that connect with the client who can add you required permissions or try with other account which had these permissions.

Reference MS [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-assign-permissions?tabs=azure-portal) for share level permissions.